# How to group a table by a certain attribute then count those elements that are present in an other table (with foreign keys) in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have two tables (entities):

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }         // primary key
    public string City { get; set; }    // the attribute to group by
}

class JoinTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }         // primary key
    public int Person_Id { get; set; }  // foreign key referencing a Person entity/row

    public int SomeOther_Id { get; set; } // foreign key referencing some other irrelevant entity/row
}
```

I want to group all Person entities by their "City" attribute and count how many people are referenced in the JoinTable by each city.
How do I query that in LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to acchieve. But i think something like this:

```
// Example Data (would be great if you could write some in your questions..)
List<Person> ps = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { Id = 1, City = "Cologne" },
    new Person() { Id = 2, City = "Cologne" },
    new Person() { Id = 3, City = "Berlin" },
    new Person() { Id = 4, City = "Berlin" },
};
List<JoinTable> join = new List<JoinTable>()
{
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 1, SomeOther_Id = 1000 },
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 1, SomeOther_Id = 2000 },
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 2, SomeOther_Id = 1000 },
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 2, SomeOther_Id = 2000 },
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 3, SomeOther_Id = 3000 },
    new JoinTable() { Id = 1, Person_Id = 3, SomeOther_Id = 4000 },
};

// Join the Table and select a new object.
var tmp = ps.Join(
    join, // which table/list should be joined
    o => o.Id, // key of outer list
    i => i.Person_Id, // key of inner list
    (o, i) => new { City = o.City, Id = i.Id, SomeOtherId = i.SomeOther_Id}); // form a new object with three properties..

// now we can group out new objects
var groupingByCity = tmp.GroupBy(g => g.City);

// let's see what we got..
foreach (var g in groupingByCity)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key + ": " + g.Count());

    foreach (var g2 in g.GroupBy(a => a.SomeOtherId)) // And yes we can group out values again..
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + g2.Key + ": " + g2.Count());
    }
}
```